# Exiftool - Keyword more than 64 character

Tags: metadata, keyword, tiff, exiftool

I'm trying to use Exiftool to write metadata for my tif type file. Everything was fine until I try to write value for Keyword in metadata. I found that Keyword only accepts 64 characters at one time. I also found that by using `+` symbol we managed to write more than 64 characters in Keyword, but it was separated by `;` for each keyword I wrote. For an example, if I write Keyword 3 times using the `+` it added `;` 3 times. Is there anyway I can write the Keyword without the `;`. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the "-sep" option before writing the tags
-sep", "
See [17. "List-type tags do not behave as expected"](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html)